# Can't set UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have a class that parses the result of a web service call. Based on that result it calls a method in another class and that method is supposed to change the image in a UIImageView. But it won't set the image and I have no idea why.

First class relevant parts. 'Server' value does come back "rb".

```
#import "GetBBYprod.h"
#import "MyViewController.h"

static NSString *kAblue = @"A_blue.png";
static NSString *kBblue = @"B_blue.png";
static NSString *kCblue = @"C_blue.png";

@implementation GetBBYprod
@synthesize vc;

-(id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        vc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)conn {
    NSString *bbyProdString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:bbyProdData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *server = [bbyProdString substringToIndex:2];

    if ([server isEqualToString:@"rb"]) {
    [vc setAlight:kBblue];
    }
}
```

So that sends kBblue to the method setAlight in my MyViewController class. (The value of kBblue is "B_blue.png".

So in my MyViewController class, setAlight method:

```
-(id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        aImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        bImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        cImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)setAlight:(NSString *)aValue {
    NSLog(@"image name: %@", aValue);
    [aImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:aValue]];
}
```

That will successfully log "image name: B_blue.png" so I know the data is being passed and the method is being called. But it won't set the image in the aImage UIImageView. Why?

**EDIT**

- I'm using a xib and the imageView is assigned a default image.
- All of my connections are connected in the xib and they all look correct.
- There is no whitespace in the string that I'm passing.
- I can tell that the image hasn't been set because it will be very obvious to me when it's set correctly.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't whitespace at the end of aValue? A simple test is to do ```NSLog(@"image name: [%@]", aValue);``` and see if the ] is really right after the last file name character.

Comment: How do you verify that the image has not been set?

Comment: Maybe a threading thing?  You can only do UI things from the main thread.  Maybe try [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setAlight:) withObject:kBblue waitUntilDone:NO];

Comment: You are creating `aImage` and and you are doing `[aImage setImage:...]`. But I don't see where you are (a) adding `aImage` as a subview of another view, nor (b) where you're setting its frame and the like.

Comment: Are you using XIBs? It could be as simple as forgetting to hook up an outlet. At best, everyone is guessing at what the issue could be. Please explain more about what you've tried in your tests. More code would probably help.

Comment: Here's a guess other commenters didn't cover. Check if the image is in your bundle at the right place and named appropriately. UIImage *aImageVec = [UIImage imageNamed:aValue];[aImage setImage:aImageVec];NSLog(@"Image = %x",aImageVec); (It shouldn't be 0).

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating your `UImageViews` in your xib, that don't initialize them in `init`. The framework will create them for you. Just make sure your `UIImageViews` are hooked up to the correct `IBOutlets` in your .h file.

Answer (score -1):

You say you're using xibs, but you're alloc init'ing a new aImage --  you should be using the IBOutlet to the image view that you made in IB, not creating a new one.

Comment: @Selch, well, if you actually have an image called B_blue.png in your bundle, then it should work if you've connected the IBOutlet correctly.  Did you get rid of the [[UIImageView alloc] init] statements? Did you try logging your IBOutlet to see if it returns the expected object?